# How to test Sequelize in Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, unit-testing, sequelize.js

I initialize a sequelize db in the `database/index.ts` file with the following code:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';

const {
  DATABASE_DIALECT,
  DATABASE_HOST,
  DATABASE_PORT,
  DATABASE_USER_NAME,
  DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD,
  DATABASE_NAME,
  ENVIRONMENT
} = process.env;

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  host: DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +(DATABASE_PORT as string),
  dialect: DATABASE_DIALECT as 'postgres',
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  username: DATABASE_USER_NAME,
  password: DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD,
  logging:
    (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'production' || (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'acceptance'
      ? false
      : console.log,
  query: {
    raw: true // Receive a plain object/array as a response from Sequelize (default response contains a lot of Sequelize metadata)
  }
});


export default sequelize;
```

I need to test the `logging` property cause it determines by the ternary operator that checks ENV.
To test this, I need to check arguments with whose `new Sequelize(...)` is called.

How this could be done in Jasmine? I read a lot of articles and looks like we can't spy on the `Sequelize` class itself to check call parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Sequelize a great deal, but the value passed for `logging` seems to end up under `sequelize.options.logging` (based on https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/lib/sequelize.js#L277). So referring to `sequelize.options.logging` in tests might be the quickest approach.

---

Another approach might be to store the object literal (that's passed to the `Sequelize` constructor) in a variable. Then export the variable (to make it available in tests) and also pass the variable to `Sequelize` (to continue with the instantiation). Something like:

```
export const sequelizeOptions = {
  host: DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +(DATABASE_PORT as string),
  dialect: DATABASE_DIALECT as 'postgres',
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  username: DATABASE_USER_NAME,
  password: DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD,
  logging:
    (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'production' || (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'acceptance'
      ? false
      : console.log,
  query: {
    raw: true // Receive a plain object/array as a response from Sequelize (default response contains a lot of Sequelize metadata)
  }
};

const sequelize = new Sequelize(sequelizeOptions);

export default sequelize;
```

In theory, the above should work the same as what you have now. Only difference it captures and exposes the object.

---

Another approach might be to instead create a thin wrapper around `console.log` so that you can spy on the wrapper -- and then pass the wrapper as part of the constructor options:

```
export const logger = (...args: any[]) => console.log(...args);

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
  host: DATABASE_HOST,
  port: +(DATABASE_PORT as string),
  dialect: DATABASE_DIALECT as 'postgres',
  database: DATABASE_NAME,
  username: DATABASE_USER_NAME,
  password: DATABASE_USER_PASSWORD,
  logging:
    (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'production' || (ENVIRONMENT as string) === 'acceptance'
      ? false
      : logger,
  query: {
    raw: true // Receive a plain object/array as a response from Sequelize (default response contains a lot of Sequelize metadata)
  }
});
```